# How to recursively search UP a Gremlin TinkerPop tree using Until and In

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I have a TinkerPop Graph on a Gremlin Server and I'm trying to recursively search up a tree from a leaf until I can get to the root.

Given a tree that looks like this [image]
I can query Items and Packages off of a known Shipment via this.

```
g.V("MyShipment").repeat(out().not(hasLabel("contracted", "contains")).simplePath()).until(outE().count().is(0)).path()
```

However trying to do the reverse fails

```
g.V("MyItem2").repeat(in().not(hasLabel("contracted", "contains")).simplePath()).until(inE().count().is(0)).path()
```

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
> startup failed: Script61.groovy: 1: unexpected token: in @ line 1,
> column 23.    g.V("MyItem2").repeat(in().not(hasLabel("contracted","contains")).simplePath()).until(inE().count().is(0)).path()
> ^
>
> 1 error

Is there anyway to recursively look up a tree via In Edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `in` keyword is a reserved word in Groovy. Try using

```java
g.V("MyItem2").
  repeat(__.in().not(hasLabel("contracted","contains")).simplePath()).
  until(inE().count().is(0)).
  path()
```

Note that you can also write the query as

```java
g.V("MyItem2").
  repeat(__.in().not(hasLabel("contracted","contains")).simplePath()).
  until(__.not(__.in())).
  path()
```